# How to run multiple websites using a single Magento installation?

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I have two domains, http://xxxx.com/website_one and http://xxxx.com/website_two

Now I use them with **single Magento database and structure**

My Magento is installed http://xxxx.com/website_one and I created root category, website, store and store view for the second domain.

Now my queries are following

1. Is second domain point to the first domain?
2. Can I create only two files .htaccess and index.php on second domain and how to use it?

Please suggest me how i do that?

Comment: Have you both website already created in admin ?

Comment: @user3793635 Yes I have  created.

Comment: Have you assign theme as per store from admin ?

Comment: my query is that 
how second website will run?
How to point it first website magneto structure?

Answer (score 0):

**create new root folder name as "website_two"**

**1. and copy index.php and .htacces file from root to "website_two"**

**2. change the code of end of file website_two/index.php**

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'website_two';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';
```

**after applying test both websites**

Comment: Both domain have different-different root, so is it possible on different root ?
means i copy index.php and .htaccess from domin where magetno installed to second domain so is it right?

Comment: Please follow this article  : https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains